Generate object property assertion with specific conditions
suppose that I have some classes: A, R, S, I and C. I also have some object properties: needsI, hasS, hasC and mustR. Now if I have an instance a0 that has needsI, hasS and hasC, I want to has mustR too. I wrote this general axiom for R:
((A) and (needsI some I) and (hasS some S) and (hasC some C)) SubClassOf (mustR some R)

But when I start the reasoner it cannot conclude this and a0 has not the mustR R object property. I know mustR is not a class but I don't want to create a class for this. I want to conclude property not class.

You cannot conclude mustR, but you can conclude mustR some R, which is known as an class expression or an anonymous class. Reasoners determine inferences in terms of known classes, not anonymous classes.
Hence to get the inference mustR some R, you must add an axiom that gives a class name to the class expression mustR some R, i.e.
B equivalentTo: mustR some R

This will work if for a0 you made assertions for needsI, hasS, hasC.
